# C# application doesn't close

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, multithreading

I'm having a trouble with my application that is based on various forms and various threads. The threads are closing before the application ends, but even so I can't terminate my application with 100% accuracy.

Sometimes the process still continues to work but nothing is showing up (`Form`s or even `Thread`s). I think the problem is on program.cs, almost sure it is, so I'll paste here the code

```
 private static Process old;
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        if (PriorProcess() != null)
        {
            try
            {
                old.Kill();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ja existe uma instancia do SpotLight em execucao.", "Aviso");
                return;
            }                
        }

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Support());

    }



    public static Process PriorProcess()
    {
        Process curr = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(curr.ProcessName);
        foreach (Process p in procs)
        {
            if ((p.Id != curr.Id) && (p.MainModule.FileName == curr.MainModule.FileName))
            {
                old = p;
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

`New Support()` its my first form showing up in the application.

This is the code for the threads:

```
private void check_calls()
{
        while (stop==false)
    {
        string actualTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
        connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand msqlCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
        msqlCommand.Connection = connection;
        msqlCommand.CommandText = "Select cd.uniqueid,sup.timespan from contactCenterDevel.cc_cdr_support_pending sup, vboxZon.cdr cd WHERE sup.phone=cd.src AND cd.finish=0 AND cd.accountcode='serviin' AND cd.duration >0 AND cd.lastapp='Vxml' ORDER BY cd.calldate DESC LIMIT 1";

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader msqlReader = msqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (msqlReader.Read())
            {
                int timespanCompare = convertTimetoSecs(msqlReader.GetString(1));
                int actualtimeCompare = convertTimetoSecs(actualTime);

                if (timespanCompare < actualtimeCompare)
                {
                    updateFlagCDR(msqlReader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        { MessageBox.Show("Mysql actions error: " + er); }
        finally
        { connection.Close(); }

       Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }   
}
```

This one stops when the flag "stop" is changed to true on my logout function. I already tried commentating "thread.sleep" but the problem still appear.

Comment: Can you please post the code of how the *main application thread* ends?

Comment: What you can do is : when your application is in fantom mode, you run VS and attach it to you process. Then, you pause execution and display threads (Debug menu => windows => threads). Is there any thread you started (directly or indirectly)?

Comment: Code for the DB Connection Thread inserted

Comment: @Kek I did what u said KeK and there is no threads still running.

Comment: I solved the problem. My application connects with an Asterisk server and uses it as an integration to apply VOIP on it. Asterisk runs a thread that allows you to "log in and log off" to the server and that thread is always waiting for a final response from the user code part. Checking in the source code of Asterisk I noticed that the thread is not as IsBackground and as a Sleep that waits for a logoff function. This is the reason why most of the time the application didnt close and thank you for your support guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. My application connects with an Asterisk server and uses it as an integration to apply VOIP on it. Asterisk runs a thread that allows you to "log in and log off" to the server and that thread is always waiting for a final response from the user code part. Checking in the source code of Asterisk I noticed that the thread is not as IsBackground and as a Sleep that waits for a logoff function. This is the reason why most of the time the application didnt close and thank you for your support guys.

Comment: The same thing with skype.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, this happens because you have some threads that have never been terminated.
To avoid this, if you want your application to end whatever the status of the non-UI threads, you should create them setting the IsBackground flag to true.

Comment: Yes I already have that on every Thread. I just have one that runs with a while but i end it with a flag before "logging out" of my application.

The thing that intrigues me more is the fact that sometimes the application ends well, but most of the time it doenst, so with this fact I too think its a Thread problem, although they are being closed before the application ends.

Comment: If you at all can, don't close, don't terminate, don't join(), don't set any flags, don't poll any flags or wait on any events.  Just exit the app.  The OS will blow away all your threads, no problem, no matter what state they are in or what core they might be running on.

Comment: @Martin James I already tried that, it seems that the problem is not with the creation, using or closing with the threads, but I still cant manage to find out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is an overriding reason why you absolutely must terminate the threads explicitly, (there are a few, eg. the spec says that all DB connections must be closed on exit and you have such connections that are absoultely bound to the thread/s that created them), don't explicitly terminate the threads!

If you can, just let the OS do it.  It's way better at it than user code written by you or I.

Comment: So the problem is terminating the threads too early? One of the threads need to be terminated before the application terminates because DB connections, but its the only one that has a DB Connection.

Isnt there a way that I can terminate all process, threads and forms without "care" at some point of the user code?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if you have a thread in a sleep or waiting for an AutoResetEvent... and you did not explicitly set the thread with IsBackground, then the application won't exit until this thread is explicitly terminated... no? (at least this is a problem I encountered, and I solved it by setting IsBackground)

Comment: Yes the thread with the sleep has isBackground setting to true. I'm currently testing if the problem is a form that even after closing it by user interface, it is still running on memory.